# Calculation of intersection points with a distribution curve

Tags: distributions, intersection

How can I find the two intersections (x1, x2) of a distribution curve and a line y = 0.05 * Max[distribution]?

[image]

The MWE is:

```
infil = name <> ".dat"; list = OpenRead[infil]; data = 
Import[list, "Table"]; 
bwerte = data[[All, 4]];
fdist = FindDistribution[bwerte];
{Anzahl, num} = HistogramList[bwerte, 300, "PDF"];
maxFreq = Max[heights]; level = maxFreq*0.1;
d = Plot[PDF[fdist, {x}], {x, 0, 4}, Filling -> Axis, 
    PlotRange -> All];
ois = Show[Histogram[bwerte, {Anzahl}, num &], d, 
      PlotRange -> Automatic, 
      Epilog -> {{Thick, Darker[Blue], Line[{{0, level}, {3, level}}] }}]
```

Thanks a lot!!
Harald

Comment: You can use `FindRoot` on the PDF of the distribution, with an appropriate starting point. If your distribution is unimodal, you can first use `FindMaximum` to determine the maximum, then use points to the left and right as starting points fo `FindRoot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not post your data I will just use normal data.

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 2/3], 3000];
```

The data range is

```
{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[data];
```

The estimated distribution is

```
fdist = FindDistribution[data];
```

The distribution's maximum is

```
max = Maximize[{PDF[fdist, x], xmin <= x <= xmax}, x]

(* {0.607209, {x -> 2.00522}} *)
```

You stated two different values for level: `0.05 Max[distribution]` and `maxFreq*0.1`. I used the first.

```
level = 5/100 max[[1]];

sol = Quiet[
  NSolve[
   {PDF[fdist, x] == level,
    xmin <= x <= xmax},
   x], NSolve::ifun]

(* {{x -> 0.397022}, {x -> 3.61341}} *)

Show[
 Histogram[data, 300, "PDF"],
 Plot[{PDF[fdist, x], level}, {x, xmin, xmax}],
 Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[5],
   Point[{x, level} /. sol]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This is exactly what I was looking for!!!